# How to pass in variable into Django Form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I've been reading lots of questions like this on stackoverflow but none seem to work. All I want to do is make a filtered form dropdown. I'm not sure how do go about doing it. I get the error that main is not defined... but I'm sure that's because it's not initialized or something? I'm very confused lol.

My form code looks like this:

```
class AssignForm(ModelForm):

class Meta():
    model = Address
    fields = ['overseer','publisher', 'status']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs,):
    super(AssignForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['publisher'].queryset = Publisher.objects.filter(service_group=main)
```

Here is my View:

```
def assignment(request, pk_a):

assign = Address.objects.get(id=pk_a)
num = request.user.overseer.publisher_set.first()
main = num.service_group.id
print(main)
```

I would like to use the variable: main inside my form dropdown so I can limit the dropdown relative to the overseer. How can this be accomplished? Thanks!

```
form = AssignForm(main, request.POST, instance=assign)

context = {'form':form,}
return render(request, 'sms/assign.html', context )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your form to

```
class AssignForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = Address
        fields = ['overseer','publisher', 'status']

    def __init__(self, main, *args, **kwargs,):
        super(AssignForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['publisher'].queryset = Publisher.objects.filter(service_group=main)
```

and change your Form instantiation in views to

```
form = AssignForm(main, request.POST, instance=assign)
```

Comment: Yes!!! Thanks a bunch, I knew I was close just missing something smh. Appreciate it so much!

Comment: Do accept the answer and upvote if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: Just did right now. I don't think my upvote was reflected because of me being new.